# Azure Media Player controls missing css classes

Tags: azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I have a component using Azure Media Player (my videos have AES encryption) and when I set the `controls` property to true all I have is a lot of giant letter through the screen:

[image: Controls with missing css classes]

If I inspect these giant letters, I can see css classes (like `vjs-remaining-time-display`) that don't exist in the amp css file:

[image: vjs-remaining-time-display]
[image: class doesnt exist]

How could it be possible for the player to create elements with classes that don't exist? How can I fix this?

Thanks.

For those who want to reproduce, problem can be seen here: https://codepen.io/ricardogaefke/pen/eYxaGgO or you can clone https://github.com/RicardoGaefke/azuremediaplayer.git.

All you need after cloning is running `npm install` and `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I just replaced:

```
      <video
        id="videoAMP"
        ref={videoAMPRef}
      />
```

with:

```
      <video
        id="videoAMP"
        ref={videoAMPRef}
        className="azuremediaplayer amp-big-play-centered amp-default-skin"
      />
```